# NumberPicker rendered incorrectly in a Dialog

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have a NumberPicker inside an AlertDialog instantiated like this: `final NumberPicker np = new NumberPicker(PiattoActivity.this);`.

The problem is, instead of being rendered like this (on the left):

[image: from android docs]

it's rendered like this:

[image]

Why the dividers take up all the space given? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using for the picker

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

You should use

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
```