# AlertDialog with NumberPicker rendered incorrectly

Tags: android, rendering, android-alertdialog, numberpicker

I' have a problem about 'rendering' with my NumberPicker inside an AlertDialog.
I show to you the code:

```
                //setup del dialog
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                builder.setCancelable(false);

                final NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(activity);
                picker.setMinValue(0);
                picker.setMaxValue(5);
                //set bottoni dialog
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_btn_seleziona, seleziona);
                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_btn_annulla, null);

                //visualizzo il dialog
                Dialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
```

the problem is that instead of to have a result like this:
[image]

I have this result:
[image]

The blue line selector is too long, i would like the same lenght of the first picture
i founded this topic:
[NumberPicker rendered incorrectly in a Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857623/numberpicker-rendered-incorrectly-in-a-dialog)
that explain how to fix this problem, and the solution is:
instead of this

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

You should use

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

the problem is that i dont have a layout (made by myself for this numberpicker) so i need to set this parameters programmatically, but i don't know how.

Comment: your code AND comment should be in english in order to let every body understand including you (imagine chinese comment, it's worthless for you)

Comment: the code is in english. about the popup? try to open a liiiiiittle bit your imagination. cheers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood earlier. You just need to create a parent view and put your picker inside of that, using wrap_content. Here is how you do that in code:

```
final NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(activity);
picker.setMinValue(0);
picker.setMaxValue(5);
final FrameLayout parent = new FrameLayout(activity);
parent.addView(picker, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        Gravity.CENTER));
builder.setView(parent);
```